# The session has been lost: you have been logged off

Tags: tomcat7, war

I created a .war file of my application, placed it in a tomcat folder and configured it to connect to a database. Upon clicking 'startup' in bin, i'm connected to the database. However when i put my url in the browser : `http://localhost:8080/TEST/` the application is not opening, instead i'm getting an alert : `The session has been lost: you have been logged off`
Any help on this case?